# flash movie plays itself when you call any, even unnamed, function in the bytesLoaded==bytesTotal if clause

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, playback

I actually don't need help, i just want to know your opinion about that weird Flash CS4 (AS3) behavior. 
there should be something i missed.
1) what happens: flash movie plays on any (even non-existent) function call between if(bytesLoaded==bytesTotal), and doesnot play on commented-out or blank line there.
2) what should be seen instead: no action - i dont call any timeline functions so the movie shouldn't be playing.
any warning or error? i dont know, flash is so *-nixy all the time in the way it handles errors.
3) where: in the

```
if(stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded==stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
```

clause on the first frame (AS3)

I think adobe has taken responsibilty on itself to guess that if we use bytesLoaded and bytesTotal, then we want to play movie :|. what if i want to ceil a number and dont want to play it?

i dont use custom document class so i use root.* instead of MovieClip(root).*

---this is the AS3 code on the first frame, and embedded video in the next 1999 frames

```
stop();


root.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,RootOnEnterFrame);

function RootOnEnterFrame (evt:Event) {
 if(stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded==stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal){

                   //anyfunctionname(anynumber);

             Math.ceil(1599);

                   funcdoesnotexists(7);                   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that webservers do not always tell the browser how big the file is. Unfortunately Flash interprets this as `bytesTotal` to be `0`. And of course, `0 == 0` is true.

You can either let your swf know the size beforehand or configure the webserver to send this info. The former is the most common way to get around this.

Comment: bitc,
thank you for your reply.

in fact, the SWF played was in the Flash IDE, and the funny part is that it thinks that even Math.ceil() is a play() function, not more not less. 

I think Macromedia-and-then-Adobe accompanies ActionScript with overwhelmed forgiveness - thinking something like 'of course, if the programmer checks for bytesLoaded, then he obviously wants to play a movie'. I can't think of any more probable answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hey, i think no one has the idea except Adobe/flash people from Macromedia.

Thanks for replying.